# What's the best way to create an InputStream from a Jackson JsonNode?

Tags: java, jackson, inputstream

I would like to find the most clever way to create an `InputStream` from a `JsonNode`, of the Java library Jackson.

Until now I have done:

```
IOUtils.toInputStream(jsonNode.toString());
```

But this way converts the `JsonNode` into a `String` before creating the `InputStream`.

ex of need:

```
org.apache.http.entity.InputStreamEntity entity = new InputStreamEntity(IOUtils.toInputStream(jsonNode.toString()));
```

Comment: Why do you want an `InputStream`? What do you plan to do with it?

Comment: I need an inputstream because the signature of the method I call has a parameter of type InputStream

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Why is the method used 'not so clever'?

Comment: I just wonder if it's the best possible way :)

Comment: Actually, `jsonNode.toString()` is an explicit serialization of our JsonNode, but internal to JsonNode System and human readable. Maybe there are ways to implicitely serialize the JsonNode with a writer or a helper instead of calling `jsonNode.toString()`

Comment: Use ObjectMapper (http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.8/), that is probably what you are looking for

Answer (score 3):

1. In most cases JSON is written as UTF-8 and you can save some memory, if you directly generate byte array using ObjectMapper.

   ```
   ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
   JsonNode json = ...; 
   byte[] bytes = objectMapper.writeValueAsBytes(json);
   ```

   Specifically, Apache HTTP client provides ByteArrayEntity for use with byte array. For other uses, there is a ByteArrayInputStream.

   Of course, ObjectMapper should be created only once and reused.
2. If you really want JSON to be written in a streaming manner, it is possible to use a pair of PipedInputStream and PipedOutputStream, however, as JavaDoc states

   > Typically, data is read from a `PipedInputStream` object by one thread  and data is written to the corresponding `PipedOutputStream` by some other thread. Attempting to use both objects from a single thread is not recommended, as it may deadlock the thread.

   Example:

   ```
   ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
   JsonNode json = ...; 

   PipedInputStream in = new PipedInputStream();

   new Thread(() -> {
       try {
           IOUtils.copy(in, System.out);
       } catch (IOException e) {
           ...
       }
   }).start();

   try (
       PipedOutputStream out = new PipedOutputStream(in);
       JsonGenerator gen = objectMapper.getFactory().createGenerator(out);
   ) {
       gen.writeTree(json);
   } catch (IOException e) {
       ...
   }
   ```